# When should we enable the `locate` command on a Mac?

Tags: command-line, bash, unix

The `locate` command in Bash is available besides `find` to look for files, but it requires building a database.  On a Mac, how useful is this and in what situation(s) should we enable it?

```bsh
$ locate 'node_modules'

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.
```

Answer (score 2):

Once created, according to the man page for locate, the database is updated, automatically, every day or week. I suppose it's one of the daily/weekly scripts that run automatically and that can be forced to run by the app OnyX.  As to the difference between find and locate; since locate is said to be a "find filenames quickly" command, I suppose find doesn't use the database. So I'd create the database at your earliest convenience and then it'll get updated automatically in the background.

Comment: if it updates only every day, then there is a risk of not able to find some files when they are there... on the other hand, if it can be made to update in real time, there might be some performance hit when we do an `npm install` when 200MB or 300MB of files are installed for one "hello world" ReactJS app

Comment: @nonopolarity if you need real-time updates use `mdfind`.

Comment: it seems `mdfind` is like a command line version of the Finder or Spotlight on a Mac so we can `mdfind image`... and to use `find`, we actually have to specify `.jpg` or `.png` or `.gif`... so far, `find . -iname '*iphone*` to find all file with filenames having the word `iphone`, case insensitive, is almost all I need